# adt bundle in ubuntu doesn't work

Tags: android, ubuntu, eclipse-adt

I got some Errors when I use adt bundle in Ubuntu. 
I attached Screenshots of them.

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

what's problem?

Answer (score 0):

Second screen just click import R.

First screen the only reason why permission is denied could be because of rights. Go to this directory and set read-write permissions for everyone.

EDIT: Also you could try Menu Bar -> HELP->Install New Software and select position on List starting on Eclipse..... https then try update Eclipse.

Comment: when I  import R, activity_main.xml doesn't recognize

Comment: During to write " R." eclipse go out and exit, why?

Comment: @user3818033 The true reason is that Java and Android are sh@tty tools to develop anything. They are two fragmented between companies and don't work as they should, but Android is many times more popular then Microsoft's products to which developing tools are in different class. The only thing you can do is delete ADT, download adt again install ALL updates via HELP->Install new software(YES, the version which we download is already old... there is the same prblem for over a year) and download SDK via SDK manager all tools(those on top of the list and those on the bottom) and 4.4 Android SDK

Answer (score 0):

Try import R, then clean the project and again delete the import R;
And clean again.

If it doesn't work, you have some problem in your xml.